# Getting POST data from WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, plivo

We're working on developing an application that uses Plivo for sending and receiving SMS messages. For every request that Plivo sends, they also send a signature in the HTTP header so that we can verify the request came from Plivo and not from a random user.

https://www.plivo.com/docs/xml/request/#validation

To do this validation, we require the POST content as a query string (eg: `To=15555555555&From=11234567890&TotalRate=0&Units=1&Text=Text!&TotalAmount=0&Type=sms&MessageUUID=2be622bc-79f8-11e6-8dc0-06435fceaad7`).

#### Current solution

This is what we have so far:

```
    private bool VerifyPlivo(object thing, HttpRequestMessage Request)
    {
        if (Request.Headers.Contains("X-Plivo-Signature"))
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> reqParams = (from x in thing.GetType().GetProperties() select x).ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => (x.GetGetMethod().Invoke(thing, null) == null ? "" : x.GetGetMethod().Invoke(thing, null).ToString()));
            IEnumerable<string> headerValues = Request.Headers.GetValues("X-Plivo-Signature");
            string signature = headerValues.FirstOrDefault();
            return XPlivoSignature.Verify(Request.RequestUri.ToString(), reqParams, signature, plivoToken);
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    [Route("RecieveSMS")]
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage RecieveSMS(PlivoRecieveSMS req)
    {
        if (!VerifyPlivo(req, Request))
        {
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
        }
        ... // do actual work here
    }
```

This works by using the object that it maps to `PlivoRecieveSMS` and doing some reflection to get the properties and values, and sticking them in a Dictionary. This works well especially given our lack of the preferred solution...

#### Preferred solution

Right now, we require a model (`PlivoRecieveSMS`) to map the data, and then do introspection to find the key/values. We would like to move the logic to an extension of `System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute`, so that we can do something as simple as:

```
    [AuthorizedPlivoApi]
    [Route("RecieveSMS")]
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage RecieveSMS(PlivoRecieveSMS req)
    {
        ... // do actual work here
    }
```

The actual authorization is done in `AuthorizedPlivoApi` - if it's not valid, the request never reaches the controller. But we cannot do this at the moment because we can't map it to a specific object inside of `AuthorizedPlivoApi`.

I would like to access the POST key's / values directly, or perhaps map it to a dynamic object that isn't pre-defined before hand. If I can do that, we can then achieve our preferred solution.

**tl;dr:** is there any way to push `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data from a POST request into a `Dictionary<string,string>()` without using a specific model?

Comment: So Plivo sends a post call but all the information is in querystring as opposed to request body?

Comment: What is your goal? Where do you want to access the Post data? Inside your Filter Attribute **AuthorizedPlivoApi** ?

Comment: @Ravi, negative, it's in the body, but in order to verify the signature we are required to build a querystring with the post data.

Comment: @n.piskunov, yes, I would like to get the information inside the attribute, btu I cannot find a way to access POST data from there...

Comment: @Ryan, can you add please the source code of your attribute, so that I could try to cite it in my answer. However, if it is the WebApi ActionFilterAttribute, you can try to access actionContext.ActionArguments (and get the actions PlivoRecieveSMS-argument from there ) inside the OnActionExecuting method.